# How can I make SELECT command from concret AID on Smart Card with Android NFC

Tags: android, nfc, apdu

I try read data from smart card by NFC and Android.

I have smart card with application. Application has AID(Application ID) `A0000006581010`

I need make SELECT command and read result.

I write method:

```
private static final String SAMPLE_LOYALTY_CARD_AID = "F222222222";

private void performTransaction(Intent nfcIntent) {
        Tag tagFromIntent = nfcIntent.getParcelableExtra(EXTRA_TAG);
        NfcA mNfc = NfcA.get(tagFromIntent);
        try {
            mNfc.connect();

            //I can read ID
            byte[] id = mNfc.getTag().getId();

            //I tried create SELECT command
            byte[] selCommand = BuildSelectApdu(SAMPLE_LOYALTY_CARD_AID);
            //I try send command to card
            byte[] result = mNfc.transceive(selCommand);
            //I get result == {106, -126}
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } finally {
            if (mNfc != null) {
                try {
                    mNfc.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.v("tag", "error closing the tag");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

How can I make SELECT command from concret AID on Smart Card?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SELECT is a standard APDU command, you can find a specification that defines it from [Global Platform](http://www.globalplatform.org/).
Building it from an AID is quite mechanical:

`00A40400 + AID lenght in hexadecimal + AID + 00`

For example, for your AID of `A0000006581010` the SELECT command is:

`00A4040007A000000658101000`

Comment: Your link not opened((( Can you share more information how can I build APDU commands?

Comment: I am sorry, it seems that Global Platform's website is down. The URL is https://globalplatform.org 
You will have to register to be able to download the specs, they are free. Find the "card specification", in chapter 11 it describes the most important APDUs like SELECT.